# "Buffers have not been created" ... whilst creating buffers

Tags: java, swing, buffer, awt

I have (what I thought was) a straightforward BufferStrategy for a JFrame. It is created like so:

```
    // Buffer
    container.createBufferStrategy(2);           
    strategy = container.getBufferStrategy();
```

However, occassionally I receive the following error (which points to the first line of the preceeding snippet as the offending item) :

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffers have not been created*

This error is peculiar as it comes and goes - sometimes it is triggered, sometimes not. I *suspect* this means it's a threading issue. Does anyone have any pointers as to what might be going on here? I'm a little at a loss, since I'm already trying to do what Java says it wants me to do!

edit: full trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffers have not been created
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.getBackBuffer(WComponentPeer.java:877)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getBackBuffer(Component.java:3815)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.updateInternalBuffers(Component.java:3800)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:3791)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:3730)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4253)
        at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3612)
        at java.awt.Window.createBufferStrategy(Window.java:3015)
        at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3536)
        at java.awt.Window.createBufferStrategy(Window.java:2990)
```

Comment: Please add a full stack trace to your question - it should help knowing *which* method is throwing the ISE. I looked at the jre sources (1.7) but couldn't find a potential source for that exception.

Comment: Is that really the full stack trace?  We are looking for evidence that you are calling from the EDT.  Go ahead and show the *full* stack trace.

Comment: @Kevin Day, `Exception in thread "main"` suggests that this is not from the EDT.

Comment: @finw - agreed, which is why I want to see the full stack trace, so we can tell him where it *is* being called from.  My real hope is that all these requests for stack traces will give the OP some ideas on how to go about troubleshooting this sort of thing.

Comment: My apologies - is what I have added to my post not the full stack trace? That's what I get in my IDE's console window. Do I have to specifically code a call to dump the stack trace somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The frame needs to be displayable when you call `createBufferStrategy`.  Also as camickr has pointed out you need to call it from the EDT.

One way to ensure this is to extend `JFrame` and override `addNotify`:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        // Buffer
        createBufferStrategy(2);           
        strategy = getBufferStrategy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swing components are double buffered by default, so there is no need to play around with a BufferStrategy.

However when you get random errors like that its usually because code is not executed on the EDT. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information.

Comment: I tend to prefer manually updating graphics, so having access to an actual BufferStrategy object makes this pretty straightforward - draw a load of items to the graphics, then simply call strategy.show() once I'm done. Do correct me if this is a horrible way to do things!

I will certainly read up a little more on Concurrency.

Comment: I thought my suggestion showed my opinion of using a BufferedStrategy which I believe may have been helpfull when using AWT but as I mentioned Swing is different. The tuturial also has a section on "Custom Painting" you should look at