# java: IllegalStateException - Buffers have not been created

Tags: java, exception

I have a weird exception in one my servers.
The same application (java, swing ) runs on several servers.
Each server runs with dual monitors. 
Same jre version (jre 6 version 24)
All of them in a decent CPU/memory consumption.

In only one of them - when I drag my app from one monitor to the other it throws a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exception. I have attached the full exception below. 
Does anyone have any idea ?

Thank you.

And now, behold, the exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffers have not been created
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.updateInternalBuffers(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.revalidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.revalidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435994/buffers-have-not-been-created-whilst-creating-buffers

Comment: Yes.Googled it before I posted. But I couldnt find any clue with this post. I generated my swing components with intellij. I didnt use bufferstrategy at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding the following parameter to your java command line:

`-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false`

Comment: what is it?   from the docs : turns off the Java 2D system's use of Direct3D.  what does it do ?

Comment: Best I know, java AWT uses Direct3D on windows by default (for 2D rendering as well). Switching it off (with the parameter) can cause a loss of performance, but Direct3D doesn't play well with secondary screens, especially when you have a graphics card that has HW acceleration of Direct3D (which most do today). Compare with trying to run a 3D game on your secondary screen (doesn't work very well). Reason is the graphics card only sets up an accelerated device context for the primary monitor, to save some calculation power.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was getting this when I would resize a window on a secondary screen. At least I think that's the reproducible case. ;)

Answer (score 4):

having tried the following,

-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
-Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false
-DJ2D_D3D=false

and NOT finding a solution, i stumbled on this which worked.

```
jframe.createBufferStrategy(1);
```

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,25021.0

Comment: This actually solved the problem, when maximizing a JFrame on a second screen on Win 7. Only add "this.createBufferStrategy(1);" to the constructor of your JFrame.

Answer (score 2):

This is the case in the Oracle bug database: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6933331.

From the bug evaluation:

> .. has no consequences other
> than a stack trace dump in a console (no hang, no visual artifacts were reported)

Comment: With dual monitors the issue is always reproducible and it _does_ cause the application to hang and/or fail to refresh the window with vanilla swing windows.  The suggested workaround (same as pap's answer) resolves the problem -- if you don't need D3d capabilities.

Comment: That's odd- when I encountered this, the buttons at the bottom of the JFrame wouldn't show up. I'd call that a 'visual artifact.' (solved by johnny's answer)